# Will apple reject my app if it has an android native widget?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am developing an app in Flutter that needs to have a date and a time picker, I am thinking of using the widget that flutter has (Which is the picker from material design), but I am worried that Apple will reject my app because of this.

Has anybody had this problem when your apps were reviewed by Apple.

The widget that I am trying to use will look something like this.

https://materialdoc.com/components/pickers/

Thank you for your answers!.

Comment: I would advice against using the poorly designed (UX) date picker from android. We got alot of feedback that users are not able to select the year because they never select the big title in the picker.

Answer (score 3):

No.
They will not.

I submitted a Flutter app yesterday that use only Material widgets, not a single Cupertino widget and just got approved couple hours ago.
"Ready for sale" :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope they wouldn't. I have been developing apps using react native, appery and flutter and didn't got the issue like that but 1 time they do rejected the native android component in my app, in that case you have to use conditional native widget for android and iOS separately.